# i18n translation is throwing error for Angular 4 - attribute

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I am using angular for my project. I have following in my XLF translation (messages.fr.xlf)

```
 <trans-unit id="sintext" datatype="html">
 <source>Social Insurance Number</source>
 <target>Numéro d’assurance sociale</target>
 </trans-unit>
```

Use this as plain text this works. like

```
<span i18n="@@sintext">Social Insurance Number</span>
```

But it doesn't work with the placeholders. I am trying followings

```
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="userSIN" name="userSIN"   placeholder="Social Insurance Number" i18n-placeholder="@@sintxt">

           <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="userSIN" name="userSIN"   placeholder="Social Insurance Number" i18n-placeholder>
```

I get "Failed to compile" error. I am not sure what is going wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe thats the problem - I copied your code into my project and it built fine. What is the actual detailed error?

Comment: It was my stupid mistake of spelling. It should be sintext not sintxt. Thanks.